# Do the polynomials that define projective hypersurfaces whose intersection has the correct dimension necessarily form a regular sequence?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and let $f_1, \dots, f_n \in k[x_0, \dots, x_n]$ be homogeneous polynomials such that $V(f_1, \dots, f_n) \subset \mathbb P_k^n$ is a finite set of points. Does it automatically follow that $f_1, \dots, f_n$ is a regular sequence in $k[x_0, \dots, x_n]$, i.e., no $f_{r+1}$ is a zero divisor in the ideal generated by $f_1, \dots, f_r$? If so, why?

Comment: Yes, because otherwise the dimension of the zero locus would not drop by 1 when you take $f_{r+1}$ into account, and as a result the zero locus of all of them will have positive dimension.

Comment: @Sasha: The intermediate ideal $(f_1 \dots f_r)$ need not be radical, so I am not seeing why the next element $f_{r+1}$ cannot be a zero divisor in $k[x_0 \dots x_n] / (f_1 \dots f_r)$ even if the dimension drops by one in the next quotient $k[x_0 \dots x_n] / (f_1 \dots f_{r+1})$.

Comment: @Sasha: More precisely, at least in principle, there could be some nilpotent yet nonzero element in $m \in k[x_0 \dots x_n] / (f_1 \dots f_r)$ such that $f_{r+1} m = 0$.

Comment: @pyon: think geometrically, at step $r$ all irreducible components of the zero locus have codimension at most $r$; if $f_{r+1}$ is a zero divisor, it should vanish on one of these components, therefore at step $r+1$ you have at least one component of codimension at most $r$, and hence at the last step you have a component of positive dimension.

Comment: @Sasha: I'm sorry for being so dense. If $k[x_0, \dots, x_n] / (f_1, \dots, f_r)$ is a reduced ring, i.e., the homogeneous coordinate ring of a projective algebraic set, then indeed zero divisors must vanish on at least one irreducible component. But what if $k[x_0, \dots, x_n] / (f_1, \dots, f_r)$ is not a reduced ring?

Comment: @pyon: of course, some components may be not reduced, but still a zero divisor must vanish on one of the components (with its reduced structure), i.e., it must belong to the radical of the corresponding ideal.

Comment: @Sasha: Ah, thanks!